# On which thread does the UIPinchGestureRecognizer work?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Among Swift Gesture functions,
What thread does the method (panAction of the code below) that is mapped to the UIPinchGestureRecognizer work on?
Does it work on the main thread?

```swift
let pinchRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(pinchAction(_ :)))

@objc func pinchAction(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
// something do.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on the main thread.

When in doubt, you can either check it either programatically, by using `Thread.isMainThread` or just by putting a breakpoint and seeing in debugger which thread it's currently on.